# Toggle between 2 text JQuery

Tags: jquery, toggle

I often find help here and i did my research and by any logic this should work, any of those 2 ways, but it doesnt.
Text gets toggled in another element when  i click #1 or #2 but it doesnt change its own html or text, i dont mind. Id like to change 2 texts on click in element id="1" and id="2" as well as i do in id="rita" and id="filip".
Most probably its simple but, im stuck, thanks in advance :)

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#rita").hide();
$("#filip").hide();

$("#1").click(function()  {
    $("#rita").toggle(200);
    $("#1").toggle(     function(){
                        $("this").html("-Sveta Rita");},
                        function(){
                        $("this").html("+Sveta Rita");}
                   );

    });

$("#2").click(function()  {
    var originalValue = $(this).val();
    $(this).val(originalValue == '-Sveti Filip' ? '+Sveti Filip' : '-Sveti Filip');

    $("#filip").toggle(200);



    });

});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `toggle()` version that toggles two functions is deprecated, but using a function call in `text()` and toggling the returned text there should work:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $("#rita").hide();
    $("#filip").hide();

    $("#a1").on('click', function () {
        $("#rita").toggle(200);
        $(this).text(function () {
            var current_value = $.trim($(this).text());
            var return_value  = "";

            if (current_value == '-Sveta Rita') {
                return_value = '+Sveta Rita';
            }else{
                return_value = '-Sveta Rita';
            }

            return return_value;
        });
    });

    $("#a2").on('click', function () {
        $("#filip").toggle(200);
        $(this).text(function () {
            return $.trim($(this).text()) == '-Sveti Filip' ? '+Sveti Filip' : '-Sveti Filip';
        });
    });
});
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/K6saC/1/)

Also, ID's should'nt contain just a number!

Comment: Thanks a lot it works... would it be to much if i asked for you to write it in first way instead of second, i presented 2 ways in above problem. Sorry if bothering and thanks for your respond.

I dont understand secodn way jet though ;D

Comment: The first way, using toggle() to toggle two functions, is deprecated, and that version of toggle was actually removed in jQuery 1.9, so you should'nt really use it. I changed the code above to include an example with an if/else, which is easier to understand, but they both do the exact same thing, the ternary statement in the last example is just shorter to write.